# Capturar datos de un celda con DataGridViewCell.ToolTipText

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente formulario que tiene una columna de notas, 
genere el evento CellFormatting para agregar un ToolTipTex

Es decir que cuando pase el mause por la celda me muestre el contenido en un ToolTip

En la siguiente imagen muestra que cuando paso el mouse por la celda que tiene el * me muestra el mensaje **Hola Mundo** en el tooltip

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código**

```
private voidDataGridView1_CellFormatting(objectsender,DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArs e)
{
    if ((e.ColumnIndex == this.dataGridView1.Columns["Notas"].Index)
        && e.Value != null)
            {
                DataGridViewCell cell =
           this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
                if (e.Value.Equals("*"))
                {
                    cell.ToolTipText = "Hola Mundo";
                }
            }
        }
```

Como puedo hacer yo que me muestre el contenido de la celda, en el código dice que si en la celda hay un  *  muestre hola mundo, 
pero lo que yo necesito es que me muestre el contenido se cual sea el que el usuario ingrese es decir si el usuario ingreso **hola como estas** me muestre esto mismo

Comment: Pero necesitas mostrar el contenido que tiene la celda o algo que se ingrese aparte ?

Comment: Si el usuario en las notas ingreso Como estas me muestre Como estas, mas no algo que este quemado en el código como en el que puse de ejemplo que dice si es  *  muestre Hola Mundo independientemente que sea lo que ingrese lo muestre

Comment: Ya probaste agregar el value ? asi `if (e.Value.Equals("*")) {
                    cell.ToolTipText = e.Value.ToString();
                }`  asi mostraria el valor que se ingreso el las notas, Pero debes de quitar la validacion si es igual que por que si la dejas solo va a validar el contenido que sea igual y para el resto no va a mostrar nada

Comment: Si amigo pero si el usuario ingresa otra cosa que sea diferente  a  * no la va mostrar es decir que no se sebe el usuario que va ingresar

Comment: Listo amigo ya entendí si me funciono muchas gracias  :D

Comment: Dale, no olvides marcar la respuesta, para que sea de ayuda a otros usuarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes internar lo siguiente

```
if (e.Value.Equals("*")) { cell.ToolTipText = e.Value.ToString(); }
```